# How can i download high quality you tube video using ytdl-core package in nodejs

Tags: node.js, youtube, ytdl

my code snippet as below:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const fs = require('fs')
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('rputer calld')
    let url = "https://youtu.be/nD_NDngrEl8";
    ytdl(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./presentation/video.webm'));
    res.end();
})
app.use(router);
app.listen(2222, () => {
    console.log('app listingin on 2222')
})
```

I have used express server and put a youtube URL, which I wanted to download in its high quality.

Answer (score 2):

High-quality YouTube videos just don't have sound included. Generally, you have to download separate video and audio and mux the two files as you have said.

You want to mux the two files in real-time as they are downloading rather than at the end of downloading.

Well, FFmpeg can do that if you provide matching video and audio URLs from info. formats in place of downloaded filenames, you can then save the muxed output to file, pipe, or stream it to whatever or wherever. The time to completion will be much longer but you can theoretically start consuming the output immediately as if you were watching it on YouTube. But then, I suppose the question is, why not just watch it on YouTube?

**Some Example:**

**FFmpeg with streams:** https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/blob/master/example/ffmpeg.js

**Muxed stream:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core-muxer

Answer (score 1):

this is working perfect download video
change **./presentation/video.webm** to **video.mp4**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const fs = require('fs')
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('rputer calld')
    let url = "https://youtu.be/nD_NDngrEl8";
    ytdl(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.mp4'));
    res.end();
})
app.use(router);
app.listen(2222, () => {
    console.log('app listingin on 2222')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For your requirements "High Quality" you can use the filter function to return the video with the highest format

```
const video = ytdl(url, {
  filter: function (format) {
    return format.quality== "highest";
  },
});
```

Or using the quality's [itag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_formats) which is a constant number for each quality (ex. for 720p itag = 22)

```
const iTag = 22;
const video = ytdl(url, {
  filter: function (format) {
    return format.itag === iTag;
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the npm package "ytdl-max"

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-max

https://github.com/BrunoItacaramby/Youtube-Downloader

You just need to start coping the youtube links and it will download automatically, high quality videos, audio or lower quality videos!

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35375682)